# Sharepoint Online - Popup Message if a Column Value Within a List is Selected as NO?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a List in SharePoint Online site. In the list, there is a column called Choice. What I need is to popup a message if someone chooses NO for that column value.

PowerAutomate is disabled but PowerApps is available. Can my requirement be fulfilled?

Answer (score 0):

Achieved this by below steps:

- In the OnVisible property of your screen, create a Context Variable and set it's value to false.

  ```
  UpdateContext({cVisible: false})
  ```

  [image]
- Add a label to your screen.
  [image]
- Then set the label Visible property to to the context variable, in this example that would be `cVisible`

  [image]
- Set the popup message you want to Text.
  [image]
- On the check box control set the **OnUnCheck** property to update the Context variable

  ```
   UpdateContext({cVisible: true})
  ```

  You can reset the context variable in the checkbox **OnCheck** property to reset as well to get a toggle effect.

  ```
   UpdateContext({cVisible: false})
  ```

  [image]

Test result on my end:

[image]